# Passing an _id and a search query in the string

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb, meteor, url-routing

Using **meteor** for a test project. Can't figure out how to pass an ID and a search parameter when playing with the sample `todo` app they have.

For the moment, I have in my iron router:

```
this.route('team', {
     path: '/team/:_id',
     onBeforeAction: function() {
         this.todosHandle = Meteor.subscribe('todos', this.params._id);
         // Then filter mongoDB to search for the text
 }});
```

The thing is, I also want to pass an optional `search` parameter to search for `todos`. So something like `path: '/team/:_id(/search/:search)?'`

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

From your explanation, it sounds like you would like to carefully control which documents are actually published to the client, rather than publishing all of them and narrowing down your result set on the client. In this case, I would suggest first defining a publication on the server like so:

```
Meteor.publish('todosByTeamIdAndSearch', function(todoTeamId, searchParameter) {
    var todosCursor = null;

    // Check for teamId and searchParameter existence and set
    // todosCursor accordingly. If neither exist, return an empty
    // cursor, while returning a subset of documents depending on
    // parameter existence.
    todosCursor = Todos.find({teamId: todoTeamId, ...}); // pass parameters accordingly

    return todosCursor;
});
```

To read more about defining more granular publications, check [this](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish) out.

With a publication like the one above defined, you can then setup your route like so:

```
Router.route('/team/:_id/search/:search', {
    name: 'team',
    waitOn: function() {
        return Meteor.subscribe('todosByTeamIdAndSearch', this.params._id, this.params.search);
    },
    data: function() {
        if(this.ready()) {
            // Access your Todos collection like you normally would
            var todos = Todos.find({});
        }
    }
});
```

As you can see from the example route definition, you can define the path for the route exactly as you would like to see it directly in the call to the `Router.route()` function and access the parameters directly passed in like in the `waitOn` route option. Since the publication has been defined like I suggested, you can simply pass those route parameters right to the `Meteor.subscribe()` function. Then, in the `data` route option, once you have checked that your subscription is ready, you can access the `Todos` collection like normal with no further narrowing of the result set if you do not need to do so.

In order to learn more about how to configure your routes, check these two links out: [Iron Router Route Parameters](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#route-parameters) and [Iron Router Route Options](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#route-options)

Comment: Thanks. But does that I mean I need to create 2 different routes that go to the same place?

Comment: So `Router.route('/team/:_id')` and `Router.route('/team/:_id/search/:search')` ?

Comment: The reason I'm asking is because I have some logic in the data and it seems redundant to do it twice... or am I doing something wrong at the core...?

Comment: If you want to use a query string for your search, you could define just the first route. If you want a `/search/:search` route, you'll have to define both.

Comment: When you say that you 'have some logic in the data', do you mean that you have logic in your `Meteor.publish()` function for your `Todos` collection to narrow the result set?

Comment: Well inside the route data function, I get the team info from the ID in the DB as well and 4 other variables, so feels like something isn't right.

Answer (score 1):

On the client, you would just use `Meteor.subscribe('todos');` in top-level code. `'todos'` here doesn't refer to the Collection, it's an arbitrary string. Subscriptions don't care about what route you're on.

On the server, you would have a publish function like this:

```
Meteor.publish('todos', function() {
    if (!Meteor.userId()) return;

    // return all todos (you could pass whatever query params)
    return Todos({});
});
```

Then, on your route definition:

```
Router.route('team', {
    path: '/team/:_id',
    data: function() {
        if (this.params.query) { //if there's a query string
             return Todos.find(/* according to the query string */).fetch();
        else {
             // return all the user's todos
             return Todos.find({ uid: this.params._id }).fetch();
        }
    }
});
```